# Failed to track my own camera in QuickBlox

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm implementing the QuickBlox framework for a video chat application.

I laid out a UIView and customized it into `QBGLVideoView` in storyboard.
It gave me an error when that view controller is shown and i tried to change the parameters of the `QBGLVideoView`, but no luck.

This is the current code and error.

```
- (void)session:(QBRTCSession *)session didReceiveLocalVideoTrack:(QBRTCVideoTrack *)videoTrack {
    if (self.localView){ // localView is an instance of QBGLVideoView
        [self.localView setVideoTrack:videoTrack];
    }
}
```

> Failed to bind EAGLDrawable:  to GL_RENDERBUFFER 1
>   Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6`

What am I doing wrong and how to solve this error?

Comment: did you found any solution at that time bcz i am facing same issue my view is hide after 15 sec

Answer (score 0):

Please check that self.localView height or width is not 0.